# What are the IDEs available for gtk+ development

Tags: c, ide, gtk

Recently i start to studying C/gtk+ programming. And want to ask one question: what are the IDEs available for C/gtk+ development apart from command line interface?

Thank you.

Comment: Checkout Vala [http://live.gnome.org/Vala], its a new (2006) great language specially for GTK/Gnome development

Answer (score 10):

In my (biased) opinion and experience, you're better off learning GTK by command-line compilation and your favorite editor (gedit, kate, vi, emacs, whatever).  This way, you can learn at your own pace rather than trying to grapple with a big complicated IDE that really isn't beginner-friendly.  Nonetheless, be aware of devhelp (GTK's development documentation program) and try building a couple GUIs with glade3 and using them in your C programs.

This might not be the answer you want, but I feel that C/C++ GUI IDEs tend to suck, at least for beginners.

[Anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org/) can do C/GTK+, but I personally wasn't very impressed with it.  It asks you what plugin you want to open .glade files with, new projects are built with autoconf (resulting in a mess of over 70 files for a simple "Hello world") and localized with gettext by default (resulting in a bunch of boilerplate code in main.c), and it pops dialogs like this when you invoke weird edge cases such as double clicking a button you just created:

[image: Error while adding a new handler stub: There is no associated editor for the designer. To avoid this message turn off "(null)" flag in Preferences->Glade GUI Designer]

My impression of Anjuta from the perspective of a beginner was, as you can tell, highly negative.  It shows a whole lot of advanced options, but doesn't let you do basic tasks without a lot of hassle.  Anjuta is not alone.  In general, I don't believe I've ever found a (mature) C/C++ IDE for any GUI toolkit that was easy for a beginner like me.

Comment: "I don't believe I've ever found a (mature) C/C++ IDE for any GUI toolkit..."
What about Qt Builder + Qt Designer? IMHO its a great IDE!

Comment: google is warning with malware on the host your using to host that image.. could you find a different host?

Comment: @Axlrod: Thanks for letting me know.  Moved it to imgur.com via StackOverflow's [image upload support](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/).

Answer (score 6):

There's really nothing all that special about GTK+, it's a pretty standard C API and so any IDE that lets you program C is going to work well for GTK+. Examples include [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

You can also use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) as RAD tool for developing GTK+ GUIs in a graphical way. Use of Glade is pretty much IDE-independent, though.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I find that [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) make a pretty good combination. Eclipse doesn't need you to use Autotools, etc. If you're under Debian/Ubuntu, I'd recommend [manually installing](http://johnpaulett.com/2008/06/26/eclipse-34-ganymede-on-ubuntu/) Eclipse instead of using the repository version.

Comment: That's what I use as well. I can recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse or Anjuta IDE. I found Anjuta IDE comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html) has a pretty good C/C++ suport and if you want a designer I'd second Glade. I personally prefer Emacs + [Semantic](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) + [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) for C development.