# How can I set up a GTK+ Project in Code::Blocks if gtk doesn't have the right subfolders?

Tags: gtk, codeblocks

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/05/setup-gtk-project-in-codeblocks-windows.html) on how to set up a GTK+ project on Code::Blocks 16.01. The link in Step 1 to download GTK+ doesn't work, so I instead did a "Open in Desktop" from the Gtk Github [repository](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk). When doing Step 3 and giving the path for the location GTK, I get this error:

> The path you entered seems valid, but the wizard can't locate the
>   include directory. The wizard cannot continue.

When I look back at the repository, I see there is no "include" or "lib" subfolder that is needed to make the project. What can I do to setup the project if neither of those folders exist? I realize the tutorial was written in 2013, so maybe it's outdated. There is a 2015 YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvQXvTtSIQo) about setting this up, but it seems more complicated with setting up environment variables and changing Code::Blocks "Global Compiler Settings", so I was wondering if this 2013 tutorial still works.

Comment: I would be very skeptical towards any approach that requires you to *build* GTK+ yourself just to use it. That's not normal, it's a library product, "someone else" should build it for you and you should get binaries and headers.

Comment: @unwind, the tutorial wasn't saying to build GTK+. It was saying to build your project using GTK+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial has a lot of outdated info in it. It recommends GTK+2, GTK+ is now at version 3, moving on to 4, and you'll probably want to follow GTK's methods for installing and setting up instead of orienting yourself around Code::Blocks.

My recommendation would be to follow [the GTK+ download instructions](http://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) and the [instructions on how to set it up](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows/) and maybe [these instructions on how to start](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/44), *then* begin making it work with Code::Blocks (for which you probably need to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339805/how-to-fix-the-codeblocks-wizard-to-look-for-gtk-3-0-and-not-2-0)).

Also, with how much work it takes to set up Code::Blocks for GTK+3 anyway, you may consider using a different IDE.

Comment: I can try a different IDE. I'm just interested in trying out GTK. The GTK download page references Visual Studio, but what IDE have you used that works? Overall, I still want to try following the instructions you linked me.  Do you know how to create a PKGBUILD file in Windows? There's a github link to it in the instructions, but I don't know what to save the raw file as.

Comment: I'll try Glade from this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894655/what-are-the-ides-available-for-gtk-development) post, looks pretty friendly.

Comment: Glade works _if you're building your GUI statically_ (that is, not making your widgets and things in your code, but creating a widget layout description you then load into your project). For actual code to use that description file, though, I don't think Glade allows code-editing. You'll probably still need an IDE. I like [Geany](http://geany.org/). As for the PKGBUILD, that will come later.

Comment: I'll work more on it tomorrow, but do you have any experience with Linux, especially Arch? MSYS2 uses similar methods. Also, I can tell you you shouldn't need a PKGBUILD just for your beginning development.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Alright, I'll look into Geany. I've had very little Linux experience, and no Arch. Coincidentally, I tried out Ubuntu on VMware yesterday. If it involves the terminal, I think I can work my way with it.

Comment: You're right. I'm just starting with Gtk's [Getting Started](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html), I don't need something like PKGBUILD. But I still want to try to make an exmaple file from there work with PKGBUILD, it'd be cool to know. It sounds like a low-level way to compile and run a program.

Comment: Trying Geany, I thought it'd have gtk preinstalled or something like that, but trying to compile "example-0.c" from the "Getting Started" I mentioned earlier didn't work. I did some more searching, and found [this](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/44). It worked out nicely, after guessing from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735086/cannot-run-python-on-windows-what-am-i-missing) that I needed to add `C:\MinGW\bin` to PATH. I still want to use your link. Never did something like this before. I've done a little Python Tkinter before, and I thought this'd be fun to try.

Comment: Well, in that link is a link to Archwiki's PKGBUILD page and a sample PKGBUILD. You can look at those for some inspiration on that. That would be good if you were actually building a major project on Windows, but could work on a starting project. If your main problem is solved, you can mark it as an accepted answer, I guess.

Comment: I also didn't notice your question about how to save a PKGBUILD. You can save files without extensions in Windows too, just like you could in Linux. It should be named just "PKGBUILD".

Comment: sorry I accidentally clicked the "move to chat" link. Anyways, thanks. If I have any more questions about it, I'll ask it in another question.